# PHP Logic to generate bus seat arrangement

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a bus seat arrangement using PHP. What I want to achieve is shown in the image below
[image]

What I have so far is given below
[image]

I have the following script in place

```
$divide = 4;
$inside = 2;
for($i = 1; $i <= 45; $i++){
    if($i % $divide == 1){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td width='15%' align='center'>".$i."</td>";
    if($i % $inside == 0 && $i % $divide != 0){
        echo "<td width='40%'>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    if($i % $divide == 0){
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

As you can see that I have seat number from 1-42 showing correct, but I am stuck in the last row. There should be no gap in the last row. Can any one please help me correct my logic?

Comment: You have seats 1-**41** showing correct. There is no 42 in your picture. That may be a clue.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus my bad. Image updated.

Comment: I repro'd and this code works. Maybe caching? Maybe some invalid HTML elsewhere on the page?

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus the logic wont work for last row. There needs to be some changes made.

Comment: does your table `<tr>` tags schematics layout correctly? (browsers can often fix bad table schematic formats)

Comment: I copied and pasted this code, and it produced a table like the first picture. (I added table open and close tags), ran in .php file  (not .html). NuValidator complained that `width` and `align` on td are obsolete. Also complained that last row is only 1 columns wide. Firefox 65.

Comment: @Martin yes tag layout is correct. You can see that there is no logic for the last row. That needs to be added and it is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in 2 ways :

Way 1:

The hall way is not viewed when we're at the index = 42

A new line is created only if :

`$i % $divide == 1 && $i != 45` is true
And closed if `$i % $divide == 0 && $i != 44` is true

```
<?php
$divide = 4;
$inside = 2;
echo "<table border='1'>";

for($i = 1; $i <= 45; $i++){
    if($i % $divide == 1 && $i != 45){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td width='15%' align='center'>".$i."</td>";
    if($i % $inside == 0 && $i % $divide != 0 && $i != 42){
        echo "<td width='40%'>&nbsp;</td>";
    }

    if($i % $divide == 0 && $i != 44){
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

Way 2:

This way is more simple:

Rows with and empty hall way are generated in the first for loop, while the last row is generated in another loop starting from position 41

```
<?php
$divide = 4;
$inside = 2;
echo "<table border='1'>";

for($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++){
    if($i % $divide == 1){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td width='15%' align='center'>".$i."</td>";
    if($i % $inside == 0 && $i % $divide != 0){
        echo "<td width='40%'>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    if($i % $divide == 0){
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 41; $i <= 45; $i++) {
    echo "<td width='15%' align='center'>".$i."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please add some explanantion as to what you actually changed and  why this worked? code only answers are not very helpful for anyone else with similar problems.

Comment: I've added some explanations as requested

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I suspect the picture is faulty and the question is how to "show" the empty seats (and aisle) in the last row.

Suggest you add another variable `$maxseats = 45`; run the loop an "even 4" times (ie from 1 to 48), and if `$i > $maxseats` print (echo) the placeholder.